# (itertools.combinations) Python Shell hangs in a bigger than specific amount size and throws memory error

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, combinations, python-itertools

I am trying to run a specific code to find the sum of all the possible combinations of the list that is coming from a .in file. The same code, when running with relatively small files, runs perfectly and with bigger files hangs and after a bit throws **MEMORY ERROR**

```
import itertools

file = open("c_medium.in","r")
if file.mode=='r':
    content = file.readlines()
    maxSlices,numberOfPizza = map(int,content[0].split())
    numberOfSlices = tuple(map(int,content[1].split()))
    print(maxSlices)
    print(numberOfSlices)
    sol = []
    sumOfSlices = []
    for x in range(1,len(numberOfSlices)+1):
        print(x)
        for y in itertools.combinations(numberOfSlices,x):
            if sum(y) <= maxSlices:
                sumOfSlices.append(sum(y))
    sumOfSlices.sort()
    print(sumOfSlices)
    checkSum = sumOfSlices[len(sumOfSlices)-1]
    print(checkSum)
    found = False
    if found == False:
        for x in range(1,len(numberOfSlices)+1):
            print(x)
            for y in itertools.combinations(numberOfSlices,x):
                if found == False:
                    if sum(y) == checkSum:
                        for z in y:
                            sol.append(numberOfSlices.index(z))
                        found = True
    solution = tuple(map(str,sol))
    print(solution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [number of combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of N elements grows very, very fast with N.

Regarding your code in particular, if (`sum(y) <= maxSlices`) is always true, then you'll generate a list with  `2^(numberOfSlices)` elements.  i.e., you'll overflow a 32-bit integer if `numberOfSlices=32`.

I'd recommend trying to solve your task without explicitly building a list.  If you describe what your code is doing, maybe someone can help.

Comment: Thank You, After reading the itertools docs, it's clear to me that it would be better for me to solve without building an explicit list